# Run svnserve *and* git-shell on the *same* server?

Tags: git, svn, permissions

I have a repository server I've been tasked to manage (largely for academic purposes), and various groups would like to use git and others svn. Some people will need access to both repositories. I do not wish to give individual users shell access, but I couldn't find any way to make git-shell play nice with svn (or svnserve with git). Is there a way to do this? Perhaps some way of asking git-shell to pass an unrecognized command to svnserve with some trick of git-shell-commands?

What's the prescribed best practice for such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem, as long as you run them on different ports.

If you want them to both serve up the *same* repository, then it gets a bit more complicated.  Basically you have to emulate one with the other's libraries, and since they don't share the same underlying design decisions, such a simulation will have weak spots.

If you are discussing the lack of coordination of credential handling, then it is just a matter of making both svn and git delegate their credential checking to a specific purpose credential handling library (like pam, kerberos, or something).

Best practice is to delegate credential handling (authentication) to something else, but administer each repository separately, with svn users (but not their credentials) managed via svn configuration files (authorization), and git users (but not their credentials) managed via git configuration files (authorization).

In any case, I would *not* recommend combining authentication and authorization in the same product, even though it is probably the *default* way to configure them.  That's because it will only be a matter of time before one gets their passwords out-of-sync, and any "reset the password" work will need to be duplicated for each product, as well as each account.

Answer (score 0):

Using git-shell, it is possible to allow access to git and svn by creating a user 'gitsvn', and then using git-shell as the gitsvn login shell. Create the following directory tree (with bare git repositories in 'gitroot' and svn repositories in 'svnroot').

```
gitsvn@server:~$ pwd
/home/gitsvn
gitsvn@server:~$ ls -l *
gitroot:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 7 gitsvn gitsvn 4096 Jan  5 17:17 test

git-shell-commands:
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gitsvn gitsvn 52 Jan  5 17:22 help
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gitsvn gitsvn 17 Jan  5 16:22 svnserve -> /usr/bin/svnserve

svnroot:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 gitsvn gitsvn 4096 Jan  5 16:23 test3

gitsvn@server:~$ cat git-shell-commands/help 
#!/usr/bin/python

print """
Restricted shell.
"""

gitsvn@server:~$
```

The repositories can be accessed in this way:

```
ruser@client:/tmp/svnc$ svn checkout svn+ssh://gitsvn@server/home/gitsvn/svnroot/test3
gitsvn@server's password: 
A    test3/it
Checked out revision 1.

ruser@client:/tmp/svnc$ git clone gitsvn@server:/home/gitsvn/gitroot/test
Cloning into 'test'...
gitsvn@server's password: 
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I believe that git-shell provides basic security from the git side. Once you place arbitrary applications in git-shell-commands, however, all bets are off. So depending on your security situation, it might be worth writing an argument-checking wrapper around svnserve to prevent malicious svn clients from passing arbitrary arguments to svnserve.